# Dependency Injection in a TestBenchTestCase

Tags: authentication, dependency-injection, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-testbench

I am starting to create integration tests for my Vaadin Flow application using TestBench, and one of the things I want to test is a successful login. In order to test the login with valid credentials, I need to provide my credentials. But I really want to avoid writing my credentials hardcoded into the testcase.

Therefore, I would like to make use of the [@Value annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation) to inject my username and pwd from my settings.xml but in order to do that, my Test class needs to be a spring-managed bean.

Is there a way to make my TestBenchTestCase a Spring-managed Bean? Or is there a better way to achieve my goal? I would believe that performing a successful login is ultimately used at the start of almost all integration test cases with TestBench?

Comment: Should your test actually be using the real login though? I think you should be mocking these kinds of things?

Comment: That is good input, I haven't thought of that. I would have to make use of `@Profile` annotation to use a mocked AuthenticationProvider when running the application for integration tests. I will think that over, thanks.

Comment: @Jay that kind of depends whether this is unit testing or system/regression/stress/performance testing. Since the question mentions Test Bench I tend to think it's the latter, but only the OP can say. If so, then he probably needs a _"provisioning/setup"_ step which ensures the minimum required configuration is in place, possibly including the creation/authorization of an user for the automated test suite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replying solely to the question, you can use `@TestPropertySource(locations="...")` & `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`, below you can find a full (naive nonetheless) sample (also a small [intro](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-test-property-source)).

However, depending on your end goal (unit testing, regression, system, stress, etc) you may want to reconsider your approach, like having an initial *"setup"* section that provisions the system with whatever data is required to run the whole suite, possibly including the creation and authorization of dedicated user accounts to be used.

**1) Code**

```
package com.example;

import com.vaadin.testbench.TestBenchTestCase;
import com.vaadin.testbench.elements.TextFieldElement;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "my-custom-config.properties")
public class SpringTestbenchTest extends TestBenchTestCase {

    @Value("${input.text:unknown}")
    private String text;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Kit\\Selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        setDriver(new ChromeDriver());
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        getDriver().quit();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldTypeTextInInputBox() {
        // open the browser
        getDriver().get("https://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/data-input/text-input/text-field");

        // wait till the element is visible
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), 5);
        TextFieldElement textBox = (TextFieldElement) wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf($(TextFieldElement.class).first()));

        // set the value and check that its caption was updated accordingly
        textBox.setValue(text);
        assertThat(textBox.getCaption(), is(Math.min(text.length(), 10) + "/10 characters"));
    }
}
```

**2) src/test/resources/com/example/my-custom-config.properties**

```
input.text=vaadin
```

**3) Result**

[image: result]